# Horizontel Overlap on iPad

Tags: ios, css, wordpress, webkit

I have two column site current set up using wordpress but an having trouble figuring out how to fix the right side column so that it does not allow it to scroll over the right side on the iPad. On desktops the page behaves as it should, however on iOS the div is able to scroll over the nav bar. My problem is the right column needs to be able to scroll vertically, so if I give it a fixed position I loose that functionality. Here is the link http://www.adamheimer.com, thanks to anyone who can help me out!.

Answer (score 0):

Not entirely certain about what you're after, but have you looked at overflow-y:scroll style? It allows you ensure an element is a certain height, and if the element exceeds that height, the user is able to scroll it.